# Logic behind order of memory allocation on run-time stack

Tags: c++, memory, compilation

This C++ related. I was reading about how memory allocation on the run-time stack happens for an executed application. I mean the order of the allocation.

In Computer Systems, 4th Ed, by J Warford, it says:

"When a function executes, allocation on the run-time stack takes place in the following order:

1. Push storage for the returned value.
2. Push the parameters.
3. Push the return address.
4. Push storage for the local variables."

My question is why in that order? What's the logic allocation in that order? I  want to understand, and not just cram/remember the order.

Comment: That description is specific to some systems.  It is not specifically required for a C++ implementation.    However, to partially hint at an explanation for one part of the question - if all those things are to be pushed to the stack, it doesn't make sense for the local variables (which are only visible to the called function) to be pushed before the other things (which will exist for the caller before the function is even called).

Comment: It makes more sense if you also consider the order in which things will be popped.

Comment: The order of the first three actions is arbitrary, e.g. on x86 there are several differing conventions. The last part is, IMHO, inevitable. Only the called function knows its local variables (clearest case - function in a dll), so the caller would prep the frame first before jumping to the function's entry address, then the called function would allocate whatever it needs on the stack.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions

Comment: That is one way how it could be done. But that is implementation dependent. Stack and Heap are implementation and not language details. Further more functions or return values can/might be optimized away by the compiler